# The multi-part identifier "a.col1" could not be bound

Tags: sql

```
update A set a.col1 = a.col2
from A a,B b,C c
where b.col1 in (1,8)
and c.col1 = b.col1
and a.col5=c.col3
and c.col3=9
```

When running the above query I get the error message as stated below
The multi-part identifier "a.col1" could not be bound

Comment: Is there a way to write the update statement where in am referencing a column with its alias before actually mentioning or associating the alias with the table.
    update A set a.col1=a.col2
    from A a,B b,C c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allowed to use an aliases to the left of the assignment within a `SET` clause - the table to update has already been specifically identified between the `UPDATE` and `SET` keywords, so it doesn't make sense to use an alias there:

```
update A --<-- This table is the only one that can be updated
set col1 = a.col2
from A a,B b,C c
where b.col1 in (1,8)
and c.col1 = b.col1
and a.col5=c.col3
and c.col3=9
```

You might also want to consider using ANSI-style JOINs rather than commas:

```
update A
set col1 = a.col2
from A a
       inner join
     C c
       on
         a.col5=c.col3
       inner join
     B b
       on
         c.col1 = b.col1
where b.col1 in (1,8)
  and c.col3=9
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `replace` `A` by `a` near `Update`. you should use alias name for referencing original table in your update statement.

May be something like this:

```
UPDATE a 
    SET a.col1 = a.col2
FROM A a,B b,C c
WHERE b.col1 IN (1,8) AND c.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col5 = c.col3 AND c.col3 = 9
```